# Getting index out of range error when creating metaplex metadata account

Tags: token, metadata, solana, metaplex

Why am I getting the following error when trying to create a metadata account using `createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction` from the `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` library?

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4464:13) 
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4423:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4411:12)  
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\util\send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:21)
    at async addMetadataToToken (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\src\lib\metadata.ts:86:16)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\src\cli.ts:48:7) {
  logs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Create Metadata Accounts v2',
    "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 36 out of range for slice of length 0', program/src/utils.rs:231:27",        
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 6223 of 1400000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: BPF program panicked',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
import {
  createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction,
  PROGRAM_ID,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  Transaction,
} from '@solana/web3.js'

export const addMetadataToToken = async (
  connection: Connection,
  tokenMint: PublicKey,
  tokenOwner: Keypair,
  name: string,
  symbol: string,
  arweaveLink: string
) => {
  const seed1 = Buffer.from('metadata', 'utf8')
  const seed2 = PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer()
  const seed3 = tokenMint.toBuffer()
  const [metadataPDA, _bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [seed1, seed2, seed3],
    PROGRAM_ID
  )
  const accounts = {
    metadata: metadataPDA,
    mint: tokenMint,
    mintAuthority: tokenOwner.publicKey,
    payer: tokenOwner.publicKey,
    updateAuthority: tokenOwner.publicKey,
  }
  const dataV2 = {
    name,
    symbol,
    uri: arweaveLink,
    // we don't need these
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    creators: null,
    collection: null,
    uses: null,
  }
  const args = {
    createMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
      data: dataV2,
      isMutable: true,
    },
  }
  const ix = createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction(accounts, args)
  const tx = new Transaction()
  tx.add(ix)
  const txid = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [tokenOwner])
  console.log(txid)
}
```

Comment: I have errors in here also. When passing args in createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction it says it is not a type of publickey. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was on trying to create metadata for a token on devnet, but was using a mainnet-beta rpc endpoint for the `Connection` class. Thus the token I was trying to create metadata for didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really Common Error Message that occurs when there is some issue with what you are passing to the program. So make sure everything that you are input to the program is correct. In 90% of the cases, it gets resolved when checking the inputs correctly.